# lost a background image after an animation render

Tags: animation, image, texture-painting

I created a simple scene with a planet in space.
I texture-painted a plane as the background and that worked fine, just a black plane with lots of colored glowing dots.In the first picture renders it worked just fine displaying white stars at the colored dots, but after I rendert an animation the background suddenly turned greyish/orange affter the first frame and from now on it doesnt changes back.
[image: My 3D Port scene]

[image: My nodes setup]

[image: My new render result after the animation]

[image: Was using this as non color data to define the white stars]

Answer (score 1):

Did you save your hand-painted image texture externally? When you first paint a texture in Blender, it's only saved in cache. If you change frames, close/reopen the project, or move stuff around, you risk losing that work.

Comment: Oh alright i found the issue.
Yea I saved it because i am aware of this problem, the thing was that blender tried to use the old one that only was saved into the cache and not the one I saved externally :)